# Why JavaScript returns empty string for "logical AND" operation?

Tags: javascript

Why do logical AND comparison between an empty string and false boolean returns an empty string? and why do logical AND comparison between a string and false boolean returns false?

Example:

```
'' && true; --> returns ''
'string' && true --> returns true;
'' && false --> returns ''
'string' && false --> returns false;
```

Question is why javascript behaves this way?

Comment: it returns the first decision value for leaving the expression.

Comment: You'll also get the same with `0` and `NaN`. It's one of "falsy" values in JavaScript. So your logical AND returns those values being same as `false` (since `true && false` is `false`). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Javascript AND(`expr1 && expr2`) operator works by returning the expressions based on the logic:

```
if expr1 is falsy
  return expr1
else
  return expr2
```

Falsy values include your empty string(`''`), `null`, `NaN`, `undefined`, etc. You can read more about it at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy.

Also for more info on boolean operators, check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators.

Answer (score 0):

The `&&` operator works very simply: if the first value is falsy, it returns the first value, otherwise it returns the second value.

The empty string `''` is falsy, so `'' && x` returns `''` for all `x`.  On the other hand, `'string'` is truthy, so `'string' && x` returns `x` for all `x`.